# Show user fields on user page if user has flagged the viewer

Tags: views, users

I am stuck with a specific problem with flags and users and views.
I have a flag on the user entity. Users can flag each other. Everything happens in logged in mode.
Every user has some private fields (managed with the field permission module).
These fields should only be visible on the user page (/user/uid) IF this user has flagged the visiting user.
But i cant get the view with its relations and contextual filters to work to do exactly that. The view is included in the user page as an EVA field, it parses the uid of the visited user page.